# Example of foreach, for in web development php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

From the two examples below, for and foreach have the capability to produce the same results for looping condition. I then search in other discussion about the benchmark and found that there is not much difference in performance between the two functions.

Thus, I want to know for web developers on how these two functions differ in handling programs.

When to use for? When to use foreach? Please provide me with some examples.

```html
<html>
   <body>
   
      <?php
         $array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
         
         foreach( $array as $value ) {
            echo "Value is $value <br />";
         }
      ?>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      
      <?php
         
         for( $i = 0; $i<5; $i++ ) {
            echo("Value of i is $i <br />" );
         }
         
      ?>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, the second loop is really not indicative of its true nature. `$i` would return the *index* for an item when looping through an array, which is its usual nature

Answer (score 1):

- When we use for loop we need a condition after satisfying which the
  loop will continue. For this reason we use some counters in our loop
  which obviously occupies some memory.
- But while using foreach loop we don't have to think about the
  counter. In case of foreach loop there is no extra memory required
  for the counters also. Because we don't have any counter in foreach
  loop.
- Both the techniques have advantages and disadvantages, the foreach
  loop is used mainly in arrays and collections but for statement can
  be used in any program.

**foreach** is specifically for iterating over elements of an array or object.

**for** is for doing something... anything... that has a defined start condition, stop condition, and iteration instructions.

So, for can be used for a much broader range of things. In fact, without the third expression - without the iteration instructions - a for becomes a while.

---

For each is used for iterating through arrays or object that use keys and values.

For example, if I had an array called 'User':

```
$User = array(
    'name' => 'dinesh',
    'email' => 'dinesh@xyz.com',
    'age' => 25
);
```

I could iterate through that very easily and still make use of the keys:

```
foreach ($User as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' is '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

This would print out:

```
name is dinesh
email is dinesh@xyz.com
age is 25
```

With `for` loops, it's more difficult to retain the use of the keys.

When you're using object-oriented practice in PHP, you'll find that you'll be using `foreach` almost entirely, with `for` loops only for numerical or list-based things. `foreach` also prevents you from having to use `count($array)` to find the total number of elements in the array.